# Finding the limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n/n!$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^a/(1 + b)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{ n\to\infty}\frac {a^n}{n!}$$ where $a$ belongs to the set $\Bbb R$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{(1+b)^n}$$ where $a$ belongs to the set $\Bbb R$ and $b$ belongs to $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: Do you know about Stolz Cesaro theorem?

Comment: @Amzoti Please look at the suggested edit before blindly approving it.

Comment: What is (are) the question(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let's $\mbox{sgn}:\mathbb{R}\to \{-1,0,+1\}$ a fuction

- $\mbox{sgn}(a)=+1$ if $a>0$,
- $\mbox{sgn}(a)=\;\,0\;\,$  if $a=0$,
- $\mbox{sgn}(a)=-1$ if $a<0$.

Note that
$$
\frac{a^n}{n!}
=
\mbox{sgn}(a)^n\frac{|a|^n}{n!}
=
\mbox{sgn}(a)^n\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{|a|}{ k}
=
\mbox{sgn}(a)^n\left(\prod_{0\leq k\leq 2a}\frac{|a|}{ k}\right)\cdot \prod_{2a< k\leq n}\frac{|a|}{ k}
$$
implies
$$
-\left(\prod_{0\leq k\leq 2a}\frac{|a|}{ k}\right)\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^n
\leq 
\mbox{sgn}(a)^n\left(\prod_{0\leq k\leq 2a}\frac{|a|}{ k}\right)\cdot \prod_{2a< k\leq n}\frac{|a|}{ k}
\leq
+\left(\prod_{0\leq k\leq 2a}\frac{|a|}{ k}\right)\cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^n
$$
by cause $2a< k $ implies $\frac{|a|}{k}<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\left(\prod_{2a\leq k\leq n}\frac{|a|}{ k}\right)<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_n=\dfrac{n^a}{(1+b)^n}$ then

$\dfrac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}=\dfrac{(n+1)^a\times (1+b)^n}{(1+b)^{n+1}\times n^a}=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^a\times \dfrac{1}{1+b}\to\dfrac{1}{1+b}<1$

Now use Ratio test.

For the other sequence recall $$e^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: the ratio test doesnt reach my goal since it states if Un converges then Un+1 so?

Comment: @ChebliFouad: The ratio test for a sequence says, if $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers with $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\to l$ then $0\le l<1\implies u_n\to 0$ and $l>1\implies u_n\to\infty.$